# data from object in object from JSON

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I want get user surname in this script:

```
$(".extend-user").click(function() {
    var self = this;

    if($(self).data("details")===0)
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: $(self).data("url"),
        data: {
            _token: $("#_token").val()
        },
        success: function(data) {
            var $details = $(self).closest('tr').next('tr');
            $details.find(".user-surname").append(surname from date object);


            $(self).data("details", 1);             
        }
    });
    if($(self).data("details")===1) {
        $(self).closest('tr').next('tr').find(".user-name").empty();
        $(self).data("details", 0);
    }
});
```

from my model:
user

```
class User extends Authenticatable {

protected $fillable = ["name", "password", "email", "date_id", "group_id"];
protected $hidden = ["password", "remember_token"];

public function date() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Date::class);
}
```

and date:

```
class Date extends Model {

protected $fillable = ["firstname", "secondname", "surname", "pesel"];

public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

and controller:

```
public function postUser($id) {
    $user = User::where("id", $id)->first();
    $date = $user->date;

    return Response::json($user);
}
```

[JSON data log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YZRp.jpg)

I can get name and anything from User, but I dont know how get for example surname from $user->date->surname in this script, I saw in consolei send it like objet in object. Howw get this value ?

Regards

Comment: Add the console.log(data); after success: function(data) {, it will output an object - after that you can see what is a response an use like data.surname or data[0].surname or data.body.surname ... We would need a json output

Comment: I add JSON output as img

Comment: ```console.log(data.date.surname);``` -> you will get surname

Comment: thank you for solve my problem

Comment: So if it helps, mark answer as accepted! Good work! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Output response in JSON is:

```
{
 ...
 date: {
   surname: ''
 }
}
```

Simillar like in php you can access them in javascript:

```
var surname = data.date.surname;
```

The 'date' comes from @postUser function `$date = $user->date;`